# SQL Replace Command needed

Tags: sql, command

I have a database with name `shop` and I want to replace some fields value's I mean I have a table `products` and in this table I have a tablefield `product_country`  and one more tablefiled `product_price`. Now all `product_price` are same 9.20 but the `product_country` are different like USA, CANADA, Australia etc. I want to change the `product_price` of only the `product_country` field where is USA only I want to replace 9.20 to 3.20.

please assist me about command .

Comment: This is a basic update. Please take a SQL tutorial first

Comment: juergen d can you share the command if you know ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very basic update command. I would recommend reviewing this tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

I will give you the command for now though :

```
UPDATE shop SET product_price = 3.2 WHERE product_country = 'USA';
```

This is assuming `product_price` is a `decimal` type and product_country is a `varchar` or some other type of `text` based fields.

Comment: Jay S thanks for it and its working when i put command check below

`UPDATE products SET product_price = 3.2 WHERE product_country = 'USA';`